# python. how to get attribute value with libxml2

Tags: python, xml, get

I was using MINIDOM but it does not provide xpath methods.

I am now trying to use libxml2 but I am having trouble retrieving attribute values.

An extract of my xml looks as follow:

```
<Class name="myclass1" version="0">
    <Owner user-login="smagnoni"/>
</Class>
```

and I wrote the following code:

```
import libxml2
doc = libxml2.parseFile(file)
ris = doc.xpathEval('*/Class[@name="'+className+'" and @version="'+classVersion+'"]/Owner')
print str(ris[0])
```

which returns:

```
<Owner user-login="smagnoni"/>
```

How do I get just "smagnoni"? Parsing the string by hand feels overworked. but I did not find a method comparable to `.getAttribute("attribute-name")` in minidom.

Can anyone suggest the proper method or direct me to documentation?

Comment: I can't find this in their (seemingly lacking) documentation either. It might possibly have a .get method. You could also consider using the 'industry standard' lxml library.

Comment: lxml uses libxml2 and provides a nicer interface (the ElementTree api).

Comment: ikanobori is right, don't use the default `libxml2` python bindings, use `lxml`, which is a much better interface to the same library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for owner in ris:
    for property in owner.properties:
        if property.type == 'attribute':
            print property.name
            print property.content
```

Comment: good... in this case it was easyer to use the .prop() but since in other case i may have multiple results your foor loop may help. Tnx for the help

Comment: ouch... i get an error doing so:
"for property in ris.properties:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'properties'" :(

Answer (score 5):

`.prop('user-login')` should work:

```
import libxml2
import io
content='''\
<Class name="myclass1" version="0">
    <Owner user-login="smagnoni"/>
</Class>
'''
doc = libxml2.parseMemory(content,len(content))
className='myclass1'
classVersion='0'
ris = doc.xpathEval('//Class[@name="'+className+'" and @version="'+classVersion+'"]/Owner')

elt=ris[0]
print(elt.prop('user-login'))
```

yields

```
smagnoni
```

Comment: by the way... do you have any link for a reference documentation?? i am really trying to guess how to use this library. I found information for c implementation but for python not so much. Even if it claims to be a stable and really good library i think it lacks in documentation.
Cheers,
ste

Comment: @stefano: I don't know of any particularly good documentation -- I mainly use lxml. I was able to guess my way to an answer here by fiddling around with code in IPython -- Typing `ris.<TAB>` shows you all the attributes of `ris`. Poking around like this led me to `elt.prop`.

Answer (score 2):

[lxml](http://lxml.de/) uses libxml2 and provides a nicer interface ([the ElementTree api](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)) so you get most of the benefit of libxml2's speed and all of the benefit of it's xpath evaluation.

```
import lxml.etree as ET

doc = ET.parse(file)
owner = doc.find('/*/Class[@name="'+className+'" and @version="'+classVersion+'"]/Owner')
if owner:
    print owner.get('user-login')
```

The added bonus is that the Element Tree api is available by default in python2.5 (though the version in 1.5 does not include the `[@name='value']` xpath syntax, that was added in python 2.7, but you can get the [1.3 api as a separate package](http://effbot.org/zone/elementtree-13-intro.htm) in older 2.x versions of python).

You can import any compatible version of the ElementTree api using:

```
try:
  from lxml import etree
  print("running with lxml.etree")
except ImportError:
  try:
    # Python 2.5
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
    print("running with cElementTree on Python 2.5+")
  except ImportError:
    try:
      # Python 2.5
      import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
      print("running with ElementTree on Python 2.5+")
    except ImportError:
      try:
        # normal cElementTree install
        import cElementTree as etree
        print("running with cElementTree")
      except ImportError:
        try:
          # normal ElementTree install
          import elementtree.ElementTree as etree
          print("running with ElementTree")
        except ImportError:
          print("Failed to import ElementTree from any known place")
```